# CustomUI for Word 2010, scrollable control (defined by XML)

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, ribbon

I'm developing a toolbar for a new Word 2010 template (`.dotm`). In the picture below I'm trying to describe what I want to mimic: the scrollbar-look-a-like element thing which  displays available styles (this is original Microsoft Word 2010).

[image]

My question regards only the element.

Here is my CustomUI XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">

  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabESS" label="ESS">
        <!--<tab id="tabESS" label="ESS" insertBeforeMso="TabHome">-->

        <group id="grpExample" label="Styles">

          <!--Which elements should be used here?-->

        </group>


      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

This is driving me crazy, I cant figure out which element Microsoft has used. I've searched everywhere on the net but nothing gives me a clue. Does anyone know which element(s) should be used?

Answer (score 1):

That's "[Gallery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbongallery.aspx)" control, specifically an [InRibbonGallery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940501(VS.85).aspx).

Example XML:

```
<Group CommandName="cmdInRibbonGalleryGroup" SizeDefinition="OneInRibbonGallery">
  <InRibbonGallery CommandName="cmdInRibbonGallery"
                   MaxColumns="10"
                   MaxColumnsMedium="5"
                   MinColumnsLarge="5"
                   MinColumnsMedium="3"
                   Type="Items">
    <InRibbonGallery.MenuLayout>
      <VerticalMenuLayout Rows="2"
                          Gripper="Vertical"/>
    </InRibbonGallery.MenuLayout>
    <InRibbonGallery.MenuGroups>
      <MenuGroup>
        <Button CommandName="cmdButton1"></Button>
        <Button CommandName="cmdButton2"></Button>
      </MenuGroup>
      <MenuGroup>
        <Button CommandName="cmdButton3"></Button>
      </MenuGroup>
    </InRibbonGallery.MenuGroups>            
  </InRibbonGallery>
</Group>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it the first thing in the morning back at work.

Comment: Hmm... I might be doing something stupid but `<InRibbonGallery />` doesn't seem to be a valid child in `<group />`-tag  (according to `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"`)?

I do not doubt that Microsoft use that control in their ribbon, but maybe I should reformulate my question to: What element should I place in `<group id="grpExample" />` (according to my example) to mimic the `InRibbonGallery`-thing?

I use [Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2009/08/07/7293.aspx) to create my ribbon tab.

Comment: Actually, I went digging into this a bit myself, using VS2013 and the visual "Ribbon Designer" they supply.  While I could add a "Gallery" object, there was no specific "InRibbonGallery" object, and no way to specifically change the "Gallery" into that mode (for lack of a better term).  So I'm thinking perhaps there's only a Gallery object, and you just have to do something weird with rows column and images to get it to behave like the mentioned "InRibbonGallery" specifically.

Comment: So I think we're on the right track, but we're missing something, like perhaps up-to-date documentation. :)  The whole subject of Galleries in the Ribbon seems to not be covered much.  Hopefully someone else will have some additional help/answers.  Plus if I figure anything out, I'll be back.. :)

Comment: I'm still interested in the final solution @techie007! :-). Thnx anyway!